# How to connect Google tag manager To Azure event hub

Tags: azure, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, azure-eventhub

Is there a way to connect google Tag manager to azure hub? I followed this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.bizone.co.th/blogs/microsoft-azure/collect-google-analytics-data-real-time-microsoft-azure) but I only got empty files on my blob storage.

Comment: You should really add more details to your question, cuz yes, there are multiple ways of connecting GTM to any data storage (I prefer using App Engine inbetween GTM and whatever storage).

Comment: Ok, what kind of detail do you need. This is my first time working whit GTM So I kinda lost. I would appreciate any help or tutorial.

Comment: GTM lets you deploy pretty much any custom JS on the site. So GTM is not important here. You can read your question now as: How to connect to Azure event hub with JS. Well, now the question is, do you have the skills to send network requests and work with APIs through JS?

Comment: Well If you put it that way. it   is sound doable . If you could point me to  any resource that explain this approach i would appreciate it .

Comment: I used something very similar for this: https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/ga-bq-stream the readme even shows what to do in GTM.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.